# AS3-PHP-MySQL: Hash user's password in AS3 or PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, hash, passwords

I'm working on a Flash browser game with a login system that uses PHP to pass usernames and passwords to a MySQL database. I know that password hashes should be stored in the database rather than the actual passwords themselves, but I have a question about what to do right after the user types their password into the Flash. Should it be hashed in Flash before posting it to PHP, and then the posted hash is compared to the hash in the database? Or can I post it to PHP first and do the hashing in PHP? The reason I ask is because PHP has a lot of built in hashing while Flash does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hash the password on the server side. If you were to hash it on the client side, then the hash would become password-equivalent, thus losing many of the benefits that hashing offers. In particular, you'd become vulnerable to a [pass-the-hash attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_the_hash).

Comment: If I do it that way, is there any problem with Flash posting the password to PHP in plaintext?

Comment: Not if it posts it over HTTPS.